# python split string and list full path name

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am using glob to get a list of all PDF files in a folder (I need full path names to upload file to cloud)

also, during the upload I need to assign a "title" to the file which we be the items name in the cloud.

I need to split the last "\" and the "." and get the values in between. for example:

```
pdf_list = glob.glob(r'C:\User\username\Desktop\pdf\*.pdf')
```

a item in the list will be: "c:\User\username\Desktop\pdf\4434343434331.pdf"

I need another pythonic way to grab the pdfs file name in a separate variable while still in the for loop.

```
for file in pdf_list:
    upload.file
    file.title(file.split(".")[0]
```

however the above split will not return my desired results but something along those lines

I am using a for loop to upload each pdf (using file path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) for this already:

```
for file in pdf_list:
   file_name = os.path.basename(file)
   upload.file(file_name)
```

Comment: this worked but left the ".pdf" suffix. I was able to use file_name.split(".")[0] to get the desired results.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), for example:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = list(Path('C:/User/username/Desktop/pdf').glob('*.pdf'))
first_filename = p[0].name
```